# What punctuation should follow after a list introduced by a colon?

Tags: punctuation, lists, colons

> The whole department: John, Jeff, Jean, and the accountant [?] were thrown into jail.

Comment: It's really a parenthetical list, and I would probably use dashes here: *The whole department—John, Jeff, Jean, and the accountant—were thrown into jail.* You could even leave out the *and* and it would be fine.

Comment: If you want to keep the colon, I would argue that no further punctuation is necessary. But it is really a matter of style, not grammatical correctness.

Answer (score 2):

The colon is incorrect here.

[There are three main uses of the colon:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/colon)

**Between two main clauses in cases where the second clause explains or follows from the first:**

> - That is the secret of my extraordinary life: always do the unexpected.

**To introduce a list:**

> - The price includes the following: travel to London, flight to Venice, hotel accommodation, and excursions.
> - The job calls for skills in the following areas: proofing, editing,    and database administration.

**Before a quotation, and sometimes before direct speech:**

> - The headline read: ‘Taxi Driver Battles Gangsters’.

Your example is a list, but it should not have a colon because the opening words are separated from their verb. You could rewrite it as:

> The whole department was[not were] thrown into jail:  John, Jeff, Jean,
>   and the accountant.

Commas are fine where your list items are short. However, there might be times where semi-colons are more suitable, to aid clarity:

> The whole department was thrown into jail:  John, who had been with the firm for forty years, had always been highly regarded and had never missed a day through sickness;    Jeff, the boss's blue-eyed boy who until this incident had done no wrong; Jean, who everyone knew had money worries and therefore might have been tempted to steal;
>   and the accountant, who nobody had ever liked anyway.