# Punctuation after a list introduced by a colon in the middle of a sentence

Tags: lists, colons

Consider the following sentence:

> I am particularly grateful to seven people: A, B, C, D, E, F, and G[?] for our numerous merry gatherings, whether with reason or not.

The question is: What punctuation should follow a list introduced by a colon in the middle of a sentence?

This questions is related to [that one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112530/what-punctuation-should-follow-after-a-list-introduced-by-a-colon). I believe this question is different due to the following. In that case, the clause is independence, and the conclusion is to reformat it using parentheses or em dashes. In this case, the clause is dependent, and the use of a colon is reasonable.

Comment: Thew answer to the linked question answers your question...if this is not correct, please explain why it doesn't. The answer to your action question is a period; you can't continue the sentence after the list. Correct form would be, **"I am particularly grateful to seven people for our numerous merry gatherings, wether with reason or not: A, B, C, D, E, F, and G."**

Comment: As @Hank says, a colon is awkward here; but you may mark the list as supplmentary with dashes: "I am particularly grateful to seven people—A, B, C, D, E, F, and G—for our numerous merry gatherings, whether with reason or not." Placement of that last adjunct, the *whether* piece, is klunky: it's not at all clear whether it is your gratitude, your gatherings, or your merriment whose reasonability is in doubt.

Comment: @Hank, sorry, I actually don’t see how the linked question answers mine. That’s why I asked. In that case, the clause is independence, and the conclusion is to reformat it using parentheses or em dashes. In this case, the clause is dependent, and the use of a colon is reasonable. Do you still think these two questions are the same? Thanks.

Comment: @StoneyB, yes, I have the same feeling about the _whether_ piece. I’m not really sure how to circumvent this ambiguity. I’d like to continue after _gatherings_ in order to make the sentence less dry. Maybe I should think of something different.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, it is still the same. The clause in the linked question is not independent, it's just organized so poorly that it appears to be independent. The answer for the linked question is the same as the answer for this question. That answer is to either reword or use em dashes.

Comment: @Hank, I see. Thanks for clarifying. I still think that it isn’t made clear in the answers to the linked question that _one cannot continue the main clause after a list introduced by a colon_. Maybe you could write just that as a separate answer, and I’ll accept it? Just for the sake of future generations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The [question linked in the post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112530/what-punctuation-should-follow-after-a-list-introduced-by-a-colon) answers this topic quite well.

That said, apparently one concept expressed in the answer to that question is not perfectly clear to all and will benefit from being expressed again, on this question.

This question and the linked question both boil down to one concept; **a colon is not the appropriate punctuation to use when inserting a list between parts of a sentence.**

In this situation, you have two main options: switch to an em-dash setup or reorganize the sentence.

**EM-Dash Setup:**

> I am particularly grateful to seven people — A, B, C, D, E, F, and G — for our numerous merry gatherings.

**Reorganization:**

> I am particularly grateful to seven people for our numerous merry gatherings: A, B, C, D, E, F, and G.

*P.S. - I removed the last clause for the purpose of making the sentences easier to read. If you need help with that last clause in some way, it will have to be a separate question focused purely on that.*

**Parentheses (optional):**
I do not feel that parentheses are appropriate for this sentence because the list of people deserve emphasis in the sentence, which parentheses do not give. If using a sentence that calls for less emphasis, parentheses can be used in place of the em-dashes in the above example.

Comment: Can you please clarify “between a clause’s subject and its verb”? It’s not the case in the case of this sentence, is it? Both the subject and the verb come before the list. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking about the other post. My bad. In this case, the list is in between the subject/predicate and the sentence's clause.